# Prevent Windows Terminal from displaying the current directory

Tags: windows-terminal

Is it possible to prevent Windows Terminal from displaying the current directory?

In this example `PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\projects>`.

If so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can customise your prompt to what you want

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7.1

also see https://github.com/Jaykul/PowerLine for more advance options